# Django Ajax Modify avatar failed

Tags: ajax, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to use Django Ajax to Modify user's avatar, but it doesn't work.There is no any error information, just doesn't work.

Here is my form in template:

```
<form class="clearfix" id="jsAvatarForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="{% url 'users:image_upload' %}" target='frameFile'>
<img id="avatarShow" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ request.user.image }}"/>
<input type="file" name="image" id="avatarUp" class=""/>
<button  type="submit">Modify Avatar</button>
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Here is my Ajax:

```
$("#jsAvatarForm").submit(function(){
    var image = $("#avatarShow").val()

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url:"{% url 'users:image_upload' %}",
        data:{'user_pk':{{ user.pk }}, 'image':image},
        async: true,
        beforeSend:function(xhr, settings){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'fail'){
                if(data.msg == '用户未登录'){
                    window.location.href="login";
                }else{
                    alert(data.msg)
                }
            }else if(data.status == 'success'){
                window.location.reload();//refresh current page.
            }

            },
    });
    return false;

});
```

Here is views.py:

```
class UploadImageView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request):
        user_pk = request.POST.get("user_pk", 0)
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        user_change = UserProfile()
        user_change.id = user_pk
        user_change.image = image
        user_change.save
        return HttpResponse('ok')
```

Actually I also have a forms.py but I don't know how to use it with ajax:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['image']
```

Here is my user model, note:I have rewrote my own USER:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/%Y/%m", default="image/default.png", max_length=100,verbose_name='头像')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "用户信息"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Any friend can help?Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously You can send file such as image to django via js, depending of what you have posted in your question, I am showing you a way that you can proceed, there are lots of other ways to accomplish this fairly.

Feel free to comment, if anything is not working.

```
$("#jsAvatarForm").submit(function(){
    var form = this;
    // var image = $("#avatarShow").val()  You can not retrieve the image like this
    var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
    // Everything inside the html form is serialized in the formData
    // No need to add X-CSRFToken, {% csrf_token %} is inside the form
    formData.append("NEW_KEY","NEW_VALUE"); # In case of further values


    $.ajax({
         url:$(form).attr('action'),
         type:$(form).attr('method'),
         data:formData,
         processData: false,
         contentType: false, //Don't set any content type header
         success: function(){
             // all your stuffs here
             $('#avatarShow').attr('src',data.avatar_url)
         },
         error:function(){
             alert("error");
         }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Django

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

    # codes here
    user_change.image = image
    user_change.save()
    return JsonResponse({'avatar_url':user_change.image.url})
```

**Note: Show the post view that rendering this template**.

Comment: Hi could you help me with my new question?Really appreciate! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164836/how-to-change-the-display-of-django-admin-when-use-manytomanyfield