# How to change the display of Django admin when use ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-admin

I'm coding a news website.News model has a ManyToManyField foreign key named **tag**.

Here is my News model:

```
class News(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title') 
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
   related_name="cate", blank=True, verbose_name='Category')
   tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, verbose_name='Tags')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "新闻"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my tag model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tag"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now I find a issue is, in the admin, the display of tag menu window is too small as this screen shot:[image]

However in practical projects for example a high traffic news website, there will be dozens of tags or maybe nearly 100 tags, it is really hard and frustrated to select a tag among so many tags in such a small menu window.

Here is my admin.py:

```
class TagAdmin(object):
    list_display = ['name']
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_filter = ['name']

xadmin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
```

So is any good idea can make it easier?By the way I'm using Xadmin. I think maybe I should change the css of that place.

Any friend can help?Thank you so much!

Comment: Try to overwrite django admin template for that.

Comment: Ok thank you!I'm trying.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761868/8495108 may be it will help.

Comment: 3 option - to write your own Form and use it in model.Admin.

Comment: Really thank you for your answer.And I just found a better way, please check my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the django admin css, and point it to that file

```
from your_app.models import News

@admin.register(News)
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('tag',)

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('your_file.css',), # file located in your static direcotry
        }
```

Here are some `class` that you can override:

```
.selector-available,
.selector-chosen {
    width: 100px;
}

.selector .selector-available input {
    width: 200px;
}

.selector select {
    width: 300px;
}

.selector {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate for your answer, and I just found a easier way.Please check my answer.Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, could you give me some advice about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278241/choose-which-way-to-calculate-the-pv-and-uv-in-django    Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi friend!! could you help with my latest question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899546/how-to-render-data-to-a-included-a-html-template-in-django

Comment: Hi friend @Lemayzeur can you help me with this quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638470/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-403-forbidden-w thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Really appreciate all the answers.

And I have found the best and easiest way to solve it!

**First**:if you are using admin, you just need to add in admin.py:

```
filter_horizontal = ('tags', )
```

.
If you are using Xadmin,just code:

```
style_fields = {'tag': 'm2m_transfer'}
```

specific example:

```
class NewsAdmin(object):
    list_display     = ['title',]
    search_fields    = ['title', ]
    list_filter      = ['title', ]
    style_fields     = {'tag': 'm2m_transfer'}
```