# How to get data from last 48 hours - Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm building a news website.I need display 48 hours most viewed news.
So I need first to get the 48 hours news, and then get its pv. 
Currently I'm using a very complicated method which is from a tutorial:

```
def get_two_days_read_data(content_type):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    dates = []
    read_nums = []

    for i in range(2, 0, -1):
        date = today - datetime.timedelta(days=i)
        dates.append(date.strftime('%m/%d'))
        read_details = ReadDetail.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, date=date)
        result = read_details.aggregate(read_num_sum=Sum('read_num'))
        read_nums.append(result['read_num_sum'] or 0)
    return dates, read_nums
```

My question is, is there any easier way?

For example something like this:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
    News.objects.filter(id=news_pk).update(pv=F('pv') + 1)
    48_hours_hot_news = news.objects.filter(**48_housrs**).order_by('-pv')

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'news': news,
        '48_hours_hot_news' : 48_hours_hot_news
    })
```

Any friends can help?Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `filter`, your substract 48 hours from his `date created`, in case its result is greater than `48 hours` or equal, you got recent news

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

thetime = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=48)
results = news.objects.filter(date_created__gte=thetime)
```

> Note a variable name can't be started with `digit` : *48_hours_hot_news* : WRONG

Comment: So if I want to get the data of the week, can I use thetime = datetime.now() - timedelta(weeks=1) ?

Comment: Of course you can and also you could have done for `48 hours` `timedelta(days=2)`

Comment: Hi friend could you help me with this relative question?Thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420252/how-to-render-different-data-to-the-same-page-by-two-different-views-django