# The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm building a news website. While I tried to get the list of relative news which have the same tags. The error said:

> The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

I have two models `News` and `Tag`. Tag is a many-to-many foreign key of `News`.

```py
# "models.py"

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class News(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, verbose_name='tag')
```

View:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))
    relative_news = News.objects.filter(tag=tags)

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'news': news,
        'tags': tags,
        'relative_news': relative_news
    })
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The following will work:

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
    relative_news = News.objects.filter(tag__id__in=news.tag.all())
```

Comment: Hi I find a small issue about this solution, the relative news will include the major news itself.How can I get the news's relative news except itself?Thank you so much!

Comment: That's great, to exclude the news itself, just add `exclude()` at the end. `.....exclude(id=news_pk)` this excludes the news from `relative_news` with the ID passed as argument or `.....exclude(id=news.pk)` this excludes the news from `relative_news` with its id

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!Because I only need 6 relative news so my code is like this  relative_news = News.objects.filter(tag__id__in=news.tag.all())[:6]   after I add exclude(id=news_pk) ,it says:Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken. Could you give me further solution ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Now I'm using a way to solve this conflict, in my view I use:     relative_news = News.objects.filter(tag__id__in=news.tag.all()).exclude(id=news_pk)  and in the template I use slice filter : |slice:":6" it works.I'm wondering is any other way can solve the 'Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.'

Comment: You must use `exclude()` to the queryset before using `slice` [:6]: `News.objects.filter(tag__id__in=news.tag.all()).exclude(id=news_pk)[:6]`

Comment: Really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi friend ,could you help me solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993171/app-cant-be-installed-in-django-virtual-environment ?

Comment: Hi friend ,could you help me solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211942/how-to-deleted-a-django-project-under-virtualenv

Comment: Hi friend, could you help me solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460662/django-how-to-display-third-level-comments-in-a-nested-comment-system

Answer (score 13):

Generally this error occurs when we use model queryset at the place of django models object. In the given question you have done the same. "Objects.filter" returns the model query set there can be single or multiple django model objects, but "objects.get" returns single django model object. Or we can use .last() and .first() with "objects.filter".

Answer (score 13):

this error rises if you use queryset or list in your filter params. For example,

```
News.objects.filter(title = a)
```

and here if "a" inside a filter is a queryset or list, then this error raises.

Comment: Yes, agree with this answer.  Just changed `field_name=queryset` to `field_name__in=queryset` & it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are facing is that you first take a filter queryset (a collection of objects from your database) for example: `Book.objects.filter(subject='fiction')`  )
and then you are trying to use that filter as a parameter (like subject = 'fiction' in the previous one ) to obtain another filter queryset.

Instead you have to use an object using 'get' instead of 'filter' that is the previous example would become

```
book = Book.objects.get(subject='fiction')
```

and then use that object as parameter for next filter.

```
example: Book_shelf = BookShelf.objects.filter(book = book)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue, try doing this, instead of:

`relative_news = News.objects.filter(tag=tags)`

to

`relative_news = News.objects.filter(tag=tags).first()`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to
> one result using slicing.

Because I assigned the queryset made by [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) to `category` as shown below:

```py
                       # Here                   # Here                 
Product.objects.filter(category=Category.objects.filter(pk=1))
```

So, I put [__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) after `category` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
                              # ↓ Here
Product.objects.filter(category__in=Category.objects.filter(pk=1))
```

Or, I assigned the object made by [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get) to `category` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
                                                # Here                 
Product.objects.filter(category=Category.objects.get(pk=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN DO LIKE THIS
list_inst=[]

```
for i in list_Series:
    list_inst += Episodes.objects.filter(id_serie=i.id_serie)
    
list_Episodes=list_inst
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).