# module can't be installed in Django virtual environment

Tags: python, django, django-models, pycharm, django-celery

I used `pip install django-celery`and `pip3 install django-celery` in Pycharm.

After that I use `import djcelery`,but Pycharm reminds me **no module named djcelery**.

Then I used `pip list` I can see **django-celery          3.2.2**   in the list.

But when I went to virtual environment path `myenv/lib/site-packages` where I can see all the module or app that I have installed such as django-pure-pagination.But I can't find django-celery there.

Any friend has any idea, how to fix it?

Comment: does it work with the solution bellow?

Comment: Yes,it works,I just install it in PyCharm.I didn't know I can directly install it in PyCharm before.Thanks friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you've installed `django-celery` in another environment. Try to install it with **PyCharm**:

- *File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter*.

Comment: Hi friend,could you help with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903751/how-to-merge-same-code-block-in-django Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi friend!Could you help me with this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084594/could-not-connect-to-redis-at-127-0-0-16379-connection-refused