# Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused

Tags: redis, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

Installed a redis in ubuntu 16.4 in digitalocean.

I've changed the default redis server `127.0.0.1:6379` into my own ip in digitalocean `178.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379` by editing editing `vim /etc/redis/redis.conf`

After that I tried `redis-cli` and `redis-cli shutdown` all responded this:
**Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused**

But if  `ps aux|grep redis`

I get:

```
redis    11734  0.0  0.1  41852  3892 ?        Ssl  15:45   0:11 /usr/local/bin/redis-server 178.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379
root     12735  0.0  0.0  12944   948 pts/0    S+   19:11   0:00 grep --color=auto redis
```

Is this normal?Or what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do depends on how you want it to work...

---

If you want to be able to connect to Redis via any network interface, comment out all the `bind` directives in your config file by putting a `#` at the start of the line beginning `bind`.

---

If you want to only be able to connect by specifying 178.xxx.xxx.xxx, then put the following in your config file:

```
bind 178.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

---

If you want to use 127.0.0.1 or 178.xxx.xxx.xxx, then put:

```
bind 178.xxx.xxx.xxx 127.0.0.1
```

I'm guessing you want this option, but see security note below.

---

In general though, it is not advisable from a security point of view, to expose your Redis server to the whole Internet - and all the options above do exactly that. You probably want to bind to 127.0.0.1 and set up an `ssh` tunnel from your 178.xxx.xxx.xxx public address to 127.0.0.1.

Whatever you put in there, restart Redis to make changes take effect.

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210606/celery-worker-importerror-no-module-named-project Thank you so much!