# Celery worker ImportError: No module named 'project'

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

While I tried to start the worker I got a issue:
**ImportError: No module named 'project'**

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 273, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 479, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 501, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 359, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 504, in symbol_by_name
    return imports.symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 104, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'project'
```

I'm using a celery and redis in ubuntu16.04 .Following are my processing steps:

First install celery and redis:

```
pip install -U celery[redis] 

sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

When I use:

```
ps aux|grep redis
```

I can see that redis is listing port 6379

Second in the project.setting add:

```
#Broker 
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
```

Third build celery.py under project folder,project.setting is also in this folder:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import django
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
django.setup()
app = Celery('project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Forth build tasks.py under app that will use it

```
from project.celery import app


from random import Random
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from users.models import EmailVerifyRecord
from project.settings import EMAIL_FROM


@app.task
def random_str(randomlength=8):
    str = ''
    chars = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789'
    length = len(chars) - 1
    random = Random()
    for i in range(randomlength):
        str += chars[random.randint(0, length)]
    return str
```

After all those steps, at the same path of celery.py  I run:

```
celery -A project worker -l debug
```

And then I got the issue.

Any friend can help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: make sure that you are in your env project, and in the same directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just because you're not at your root project

navigate toward your root project, the same directory as `manage.py`

```
cd path/to/project
```

and run the command again.

```
celery -A project worker -l debug
```

Comment: Man you really rock!

Comment: Can you help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229388/disallowedhost-at-invalid-http-host-header-www-example-com-you-may-need-to Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi friend could you please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399006/amazon-s3-with-django-cant-load-the-all-the-static-file-folders I have spent 2 days to solve it but still haven't  Thank you so much!