# DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.example.com'. You may need to add 'www.example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, nginx, subdomain, ubuntu-16.04

I have deployed a Django project in digitalocean ubuntu 16.04.My domain name is like **example.com**

Because I want to add **www.** in front of my domain name so that if input **www.example.com** it can also direct to my website.

I bought my domain name from hostgator.

I first added **www.example.com** in my digitalocean DNS records to let  **www.example.com** direct to my ip address.

Then I added **www.example.com** to **myproject.setting** in django to

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.co','www.example.com']
```

Third I went to

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject
```

to add www.example.com in nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
}
```

Then I test and restart nginx and gunicorn without any issue.

But I still received the issue  **DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.example.com'. You may need to add 'www.example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS** when use www.example.com

Only example.com works.

Any friend can help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: is the configuration of your DNS record with www correct? can you show a screenshot of it?

Comment: Hi man ,I just solved it by following this tutorial  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04#configure-nginx-redirect Thank you for your in time reply!

Comment: @Lemayzeur Hi friend could you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326766/while-use-env-got-nameerror-name-config-is-not-defined Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved it by following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04#configure-nginx-redirect

One thing need to be noticed is the form:

You should use:

```
server {
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name domain.com;
  [...]
}
```