# while use .env got NameError: name 'config' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I'm following a tutorial to upload static file to amazon S3 to.

I need to add two things in the settings.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
```

For safety reasons I create a file named **.env** its form is .text directly through pycharm.

After I added these code in the settings.py.I restarted nginx and gunicorn and then I activated virtual environment and run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Then I got the error **NameError: name 'config' is not defined**

Any friends could tell me what need I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Why have you got those `config`s there at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `config` from your `.env`

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
```