# How to deleted a Django project under virtualenv?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I have used virtualenv created a Django project:

```
django-admin.py startproject myweb
```

But now I want to remove/delete this project,what should I do?

Can I just directly `rm -r myweb` or not?

Comment: If you're on your own computer, what is keeping you from deleting the folder manually? in case you're on a server, you're good to go with your command `rm -r myweb`. Before doing this, make sure you don't need any files in it. If you need a prompt to confirm the deletion of each item `rm -ri myweb`. This can be annoying

Comment: Thank you!I have deleted it in digtalocean.

Comment: Hi friend, could you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335254/how-to-save-and-exit-redis-conf it's about redis and vim，thank you so much!

Comment: Hi friend, sorry to trouble you.Could you help me with this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354285/gunicorn-service-failed-with-result-exit-code it is about Django deployment with gunicorn Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries! I was out for the weekend. I am very glad to be of help. It seems that question was removed by you

Comment: Yes,I have solved it!Very glad to hear back from you!Thank you!

Comment: Hi friend could you help me with this question?Thank you so much!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680988/how-to-create-link-for-one-of-the-category-in-django

Comment: Hi @Lemayzeur can you help me with this Django question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159365/reverse-for-news-detail-with-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-tried ? really need your help thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Lemayzeur can you help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695610/after-deleting-digitalocean-spaces-static-link-still-point-to-digitalocean

Comment: Hi @Lemayzeur can you help me with this Django question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825673/how-to-use-the-category-name-as-url-suffix-in-django  realy appreciate!