# How to save and exit redis.conf?

Tags: ubuntu, redis, digital-ocean

I'm installing and Configuring Redis on Ubuntu 16.04 in digtalocean, following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04 .

When it goes to **'Save and close the file when you are finished.'**
I have no idea what's the right command to close and save it.
I tried to use **:wq** ,but it didn't work.

Any friend can give me some advice?

Comment: Ctrl-O Ctrl-X if you used `nano`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial tells you to use to use `nano`. If you followed it your screen should look more or less like that:

[image: nano]

Press `Ctrl+x` (`^X`) to "Exit", then press the obvious key to save your work:

[image: nano]

Answer (score 1):

In case you opened the file with [vim](https://www.vim.org/) you can save and exit using this options in normal mode:

```
:wq
:x 
:ZZ (notice that it is in uppercase)
```

`:x` and `:ZZ`  Write current file, if modified, and quit

To force just add an `!` at the end:

```
:x!
:wq!
```